# Adobe ExtendScript Change Brush Size

Tags: size, photoshop, alter, brush, extendscript

Is it possible to change the brush size in Photoshop via ExtendScript? I'm looking all through their documentation and Googling to no avail. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it via action descriptors.  Check out this post for more information.  http://www.ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=3881&p=22742&hilit=change+brush+size&sid=cceddcf35eb7a08107d95e5ae88d8659#p17448